# What will be the tension force when two people play tug of war and they pull equally hard?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Suppose, me and my brother are playing tug of war. If we both pull the rope to ourselves at 50N force, won't the tension force be zero as the net force is zero? However, practically, this doesn't happen: if the tension force becomes zero, the rope should slack over due to gravity, but this doesn't happen; it remains tight. So, does the tension force become zero or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you and your brother are pulling there has to be tension in the rope of 50 N. But if you are both holding your ground it means that the net external force acting on the combination of you as a system is zero. See the free body diagrams on each of you below.

The external forces would be the static friction forces that are exerted on each of your feet in opposition to the tension. Those static friction forces would be equal and opposite for a net force of zero. However, there is a maximum possible static friction force on each of you that equals your weight, $Mg$, times the coefficient of static friction between your feet and the ground before slipping occurs. If one of you is able to pull hard enough so that the maximum static friction force on the other is exceeded, the other will slip and lose the tug of war.

One other point. In order that there is no net torque one each of your causing you to fall, each of you would normally be tilted backward (not as shown) so that your weight provides a torque about your feet to counter the torque due to the rope.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The tension on a string would be equal to 50N, let me explain.
The since it's true that the sum of all forces of the rope is zero $$\sum_i F_i = 0,$$ implies that $$F_1 = -F_2.$$ Where $F_1$ is the for you and $F_2$ is the force of your brother (or the other way around). Depends on definition but Tension is usually defined as pair of (equal) forces acting on the "ends" of an object. From that we can clearly see that tension $T$ is $$T = F_1 = 50N$$

Answer (score 0):

A net force of zero does not imply no force at all. When you sit in a chair, the chair pushes up with a force equal and opposite your weight. There are equal and opposite forces which you feel as your own weight, even though there is no net force and nothing is accelerating. Tension is similar, you can have equal and opposite forces acting on a string that are experienced as tension, even though there is no net force and no acceleration. The fact that the pulling forces are balanced and yield no net force does not imply that the tension is zero.

Comment: What will the magnitude of the tension force be? Will it be 50N or (50+50)N=100N?

Answer (score 0):

One way of thinking about it is that the very end of the rope has to have zero net force (since it's stationary), and you're exerting 50N on the end of the rope, therefore there must be some other force countering that force. That force is the tension. At each point inside the rope, the rope is experience the tension force from the bits of rope on both sides it. The bit of rope to the left will be pulling to the left, and the bit to the right will be pulling to the right, so those forces cancel (and since every force has an equal and opposite force, that bit will also be exerting the tension force on the two bits next to it). At the very end of the rope. there's no bit on the other side of the rope, so it has to be supplied by some outside force.

Another way of thinking about it that isn't quite correct but can be a useful mental image is to imagine the rope as being made up of a bunch of springs strung together. The net force on each spring is zero, but tension isn't the *net* force on an element of the rope, it's the force *within* the element. Imagine if you and your brother were to each pull on opposite sides of a [spring scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_scale). If the scale reads 50N (or ~5kg), there is 50N of tension in the spring. Now imagine you string a bunch of these scales together, and pull with the same force. Each scale will read 50N. The right end of each scale will experience a 50N force to the right from the scale next to it, and a 50N force to the left from the spring in the scale, and vice versa for the left side of each scale.